# "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required" при скачивании файла

Tags: c#, файлы

Добрый день!

Есть код (взят мною с MSDN):

```
string remoteUri = downloadFrom.Replace(fileName, "");
string myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + fileDestination);
```

Грубо говоря, я скачиваю файл.
На строчке `myWebClient.DownloadFile` вылетает ошибка:

> The remote server returned an error:
>   (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее можно обойти?

**UPDATE**

Качаю файл с сайта [ООН](http://www.un.org/sc/committees/consolidated.xml).

**UPDATE2**

После того как прописал в App.config:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Скачивания якобы идет какое-то время, ошибок нету, но при этом в результирующей папке пусто. (

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в конфиг-файл своего проекта следующую запись:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, свою ошибку я понял. Появился другой вопрос - программа якобы скачивает файл, ошибки не выдает, но в результирующем каталоге пусто. Может, ошибка есть в моем алгоритме?